# Custom library not deployed to WLS jDeveloper

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have created a custom application using jDeveloper. Within the main project,  I have created a custom library in the classpath where I have included some jars in it.

My project compiles properly. When I try to run a `.java` file  (Right-click Run) the project gets deployed on the WLS but the jars in my custom library are not getting deployed (no lib folder created in WEB-INF).

Though, if I add the jars explicitly to the project classpath (not within a library) they get deployed and the lib folder gets created on WLS.

- What is the difference here?
- How can I get the library (a group of jars) to deploy when I run an
  application from within jDeveloper (not external deployement)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JDeveloper library for your jars.
Mark the library to be "Deploy by default" (a check box in the library definition).